# If $ab \mid c(c^2-c+1)$ and $c^2+1 \mid a+b$ then prove that $\{a, b\}=\{c, c^2-c+1 \}$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, contest-math, diophantine-equations

If $ab \mid c(c^2-c+1)$ and $c^2+1 \mid a+b$ then prove that $\{a, b\}=\{c, c^2-c+1 \}$ (equal sets), where $a$, $b$, and $c$ are positive integers.

This is math contest problem (I don't know the source). I was struggling to solve this, but I cannot find a way to make it easier. Can you help me?

All I did was like this:
$$a+b=d(c^2+1)=d(c^2-c+1+c) \\ c(a+b)=dc(c^2-c+1)+dc^2 \\ c(a+b)=deab+dc^2=d(eab+c^2)$$
I suppose this is a quadratic in $c$ and determine its discriminant. But it doesn't make the problem any easier!

Comment: Is it an ongoing contest ?

Comment: No, no at all.. Its from a book, I only saw the picture of this question. A friend sent it in a math group.

Comment: This is just an initial reaction, but it looks like a Viete jumping problem (this may have been what you were thinking by taking the discriminant, though).

Comment: I thought about Vieta, but it says prove $a=c$ and $b=c^2-c+1$. Only one solution!

Comment: Well yeah. It is.

Comment: Can you clarify your question?  When you write $(a,b)$ do you mean the ordered pair or are you referring to the gcd?  If the latter, then it is very odd as $\gcd(c,c^2-c+1)$ is obviously $1$.  If the former then your claim is false...if nothing else we might have $(a,b)=(c^2-c+1,c)$.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry about that, It's ordered pair.. I edit it now

Comment: What might help : $$x^2+(c^2+1)x+c(c^2-c+1)=(x+c)(x+c^2-c+1)$$

Comment: Another pattern with $\gcd(e,f) = 1, \; $ $ab|ef \; $ and $e+f|a+b \; $ is $a=n^2 + n, \;$ $b=1, \;$ $e = n^2, \;$ $f=n+1. \;$   Tremendous variety of other solutions (abef) as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT.-For some positive integers $m,n$ we have

$$\begin{cases}a+b=m(c^2+1)\\abn=c(c^2-c+1)\end{cases}\Rightarrow c^2-\frac{a+b}{m}c+abn=0$$
If $m$ and $n$ are equal to $1$ then $c$ is root of the equation $X^2-(a+b)X+ab=0$ from which clearly $c\in\{a,b\}$. It easily follows that $a$ or $b$ is equal to $c^2-c+1$.

If both $m$ and $n$ is greater than $1$ then $c$ is root of $X^2+\dfrac{a+b}{m}X+abn=0$ where the sum of the two roots shrinks while the product is enlarged. This is not possible for positive integers.

I leave for the O.P. the case just one of the $m,n$ is equal to $1$

Finally the proof is clear (it has been done already above) because necessarily the positive integers $m$ and $n$ are equal to $1$.

Comment: If $m,n>1$, then  $c$ is a root of $x^2-[(a+b)/m]x+abn=0$, but the other root can be a non-integer! So using sum and product of roots gives no information about $c$.

Comment: Can you give an example of such a situation? With the two restrictions given, of course.

Comment: If one root of a monic quadratic with integer coefficients is an integer, the other root must be an integer too (since the sum of both roots is one of the integer coefficients).

Answer (score 2):

Suppose we have:

$m^2k^2(c^2+1)^2-4mc(c^2-c+1)=t^2$

$(m^2k^2(c^2+1)^2-t)(m^2k^2(c^2+1)^2+t)=4mc(c^2-c+1)$

We may have a system of equations as follows:

$m^2k^2(c^2+1)^2-t=4mc$

$m^2k^2(c^2+1)^2+t=c^2-c+1$

Summing two equations we get:

$2m^2k^2(c^2+1)^2=4mc+c^2-c+1$

$k^2=\frac{2mc+(c^2-c+1)/2}{2m^2(c^2+1)^2}$

Now problem reduces to : what is condition for $2mc+(c^2-c+1)/2$ to be a perfect square.The discriminant of quadratic relation $2mc+(c^2-c+1)/2≥0$ will give a range of value for m, which is finally the condition for initial relation to be a perfect square.